# How to log only error while executing .sql file in sqlplus

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

How can I create a .log file that will only be created when an exception occurs during executing .sql file via sqlplus.

```
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE

ALTER PRODUCT IDENTIFIED BY &1;
ALTER CUSTOMER IDENTIFIED BY &1;

EXIT;
```

This script is executed via sqlplus I add parameter in the command line and it is executed when a parameter is incorrect or an ORA error occurs how can I log it into a file where this .sql is located. I do not want to track all execute just create a log file that contains the error ORA

Comment: By the way, while `EXIT SQL.SQLCODE` is OK on Windows it is not a good idea on Linux, because its exit codes only go up to 255.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid command output, add

```
SET ECHO OFF
```

To log messages,

either you may use `spool`

```
spool /path/yourlogfile.log
```

OR

If you're running `sqlplus` command-line in a Unix environment, you may redirect the outputs.

```
sqlplus usr/pwd@db @file.sql >/path/yourlogfile.log
```

To prevent substitution message, add

```
SET VERIFY OFF
```

Comment: It's also writes to file the `old` and `new` and the commands and after it error at line and the ORA. I just wanted to write the ORA error is it possible and when no error then do not write the file.

Comment: @Gorgio : `SET VERIFY OFF`

Comment: it helped me with the old and new but even it succeed the file is created with altered. What I want to get is to execute this alters if it succeed do nothing but when an exception appear then create a log file with the content, is it possible or rather no?

Comment: Gorgio : Such things can be implemented from external programs/shell scripts running SQL * Plus and cannot be  controlled within sqlplus, which is a basic SQL client and not a full-fledged programming/scripting language.

Comment: What about execute it in begin exception end blocks? when an exception the create a spool file? Could it be  done or rather no?

Comment: Gorgio : it'll require dynamic SQL which I would suggest you should avoid for this simple operation and not such a crucial requirement. What's wrong in having a log file case of success by the way, how does it  affect you?

Comment: I have different log file when user perform operation that executes this script. I wanted to attach to log file the ORA error that will be logged to different log file from the script, and after it delete the .log file from the script as it is no needed.

Comment: Gorgio :  Ok, then it should be simple.? In the program/script that appends the log file, grep for 'ORA-' pattern and append only when it's found in this log file.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create log file in Unix box, but using utl_file.
For this code should be written in begin end block. SQlPlus itself does not have capability to create Spool file on conditional basis.

It can be written something like below:-

```
declare
  filehandle utl_file.file_type;
begin

  execute immediate 'ALTER PRODUCT IDENTIFIED BY &1';
  execute immediate 'ALTER CUSTOMER IDENTIFIED BY &1';

exception

when others 
then

  filehandle := utl_file.fopen('/unixpath/test', 'outputfile.log', 'W');
  utl_file.put_line(filehandle, 'test error '||sqlerrm);
  utl_file.fclose(filehandle);

end;
/
```